# Can a bluetooth speaker contain malware?

Tags: malware, wireless, bluetooth

Can a bluetooth speaker contain malware? If someone were to find a random bluetooth speaker laying around and tries to connect with it, is there a possibility that the speaker has malware in it?

Comment: Yes.  Any device that runs software can have malicious software.

Comment: @David do you know of any bluetooth media peripherals infecting a device?

Comment: not if connected as an audio device. Unlike USB, there's no way for such a BT device to execute code since it can only act as an audio device. If you connect as a keyboard, then it's possible to do some fancy keywork, but not as a speaker.

Answer (score 4):

It is technically possible, because a Bluetooth device will likely contain firmware and a small CPU (so it's not just a dumb variable resistor and speaker driver). In a purely theoretical sense, it would be possible for malware in such a device to spread by exploiting a bug in the Bluetooth protocol to achieve code execution or gain unauthorized access to another Bluetooth-capable device. However, the chances of this are so slim as to be utterly negligible. There are better ways to infect someone. You can safely disregard a Bluetooth speaker as a malware infection vector.

Regardless, it is not a bright idea to connect to something random you see lying around.

Answer (score -5):

In your case using of Bluetooth devices that are lying around, it depends upon your status as a target. If you are working in a sensitive organization i.e. with government agencies, or dealing with any sensitive data or information, using such devices will be high- risk.

Comment: The first part of the answer appeared to be ai-generated and repeats the other answer. Please stop using ai-generated content. If you continue, your account will be suspended.